How do I use OnBubbleEvent and RaiseBubbleEvent in ASP.NET?
Microsoft has Control.RaiseBubbleEvent to handle the Control.OnBubbleEvent method.
I have the following VB.NET code in the same ASP.NET WebForm:
<System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSetAttribute(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name:="FullTrust")>
Protected Overrides Function OnBubbleEvent(source As Object, e As EventArgs) As Boolean
    Dim csrWhere As String = Session("csrWhere").ToString()
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(csrWhere) Then
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString())
    End If
    Return MyBase.OnBubbleEvent(source, e)
End Function

<System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSetAttribute(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name:="FullTrust")>
Private Sub Refresh(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    RaiseBubbleEvent(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

The debugger breakpoint on the Refresh method is called, and RaiseBubbleEvent(Me, EventArgs.Empty) is called, but the breakpoint for the override function OnBubbleEvent is never reached.
What have I done wrong?


I have the following VB.NET code in the same ASP.NET WebForm

That's your problem. Overriding both methods in a page doesn't make sense. The point is that a child control raises the event and it's handled by a parent. Examples of parent controls given here are Repeater, Datalist and GridView. This is why you should ALWAYS read the relevant documentation. This example is, in part, described thusly:

The following example overrides the OnBubbleEvent method in a custom ASP.NET server control, ParentControl. This method is invoked when a child control of ParentControl calls the RaiseBubbleEvent method.

So, a child control calls RaiseBubbleEvent and that invokes OnBubbleEvent in the parent. I'm not sure exactly what you're actually trying to achieve but it doesn't sound like that.

I originally tried calling it in the Child Dialog on a button click to load the data, but it did not work. Since Microsoft's documentation was lacking in details, I tried placing both methods in the same form, but the event is still never triggered.

I finally got it to trigger the OnBubbleEvent in my main form, but I had to select another tab on the form, causing the runat="Server" to trigger. That isn't what I need.

@jp2code, I'm confused as to what you're actually trying to achieve. I don't use Web Forms these days and haven't much in the past either but, based on the doco, it seems like this mechanism is specifically for parent controls to be notified of events on child controls. If you're handling an event of a control in a page then it doesn't seem like you should be doing this at all. I think that my answer has addressed the actual question you asked: "What have I done wrong?". I think... TBC

... that you should accept this answer and then post a new question that explains what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than just how you're trying to achieve it. I suspect that there's a much better way to achieve your actual aim, whatever that may be. We can better address that if you actually explain it, but it's a bit late to do that here.

Though your answer addressed issues, I still do not know how to get RaiseBubbleEvent in one page to trigger OnBubbleEvent in another page - both members of the same website. For a more detailed description of what I am working on, see my older question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79212960/

@jp2code, of course you still don't know, because that's not what you asked in your question. Again, I have addressed the question you actually asked. If you now want to ask a different question then you need to post a new question. This time, provide an explanation of what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than just how you're trying to achieve it. Like I already said, it appears that this mechanism is specifically for child controls in a parent control, so if you want communication between two pages then then you probably need to do something else entirely.

I'll continue to investigate my problem. When I find the solution, I will post it here and accept my answer unless someone else provides it first. What you have provided references the links I used in my original question and says it won't work without showing how to get it to work. That leads me to think that you don't know either. If someone provides an acceptable answer first, I will accept that. And you don't have to be petty by downvoting.

@jp2code, "you don't have to be petty by downvoting". I'm not being petty. You are expecting an answer to a question that you didn't ask, thus you have asked a bad question. That's why I down-voted. If you don't want to be down-voted, ask better questions. That you think the only possible reason for the down-vote is pettiness is an indication that you haven't actually listened to a word I've said.
